# Altium aluminium base layer stackup

Tags: pcb-design, altium, pcb-layers, multi-layer

I need to design the aluminium base pcb , i dont know how to set the layer stack for aluminum layer in altium , attahed the sample image of layer stack of single layer

[image: aluminum base satck]

I set the top copper layer , but i didnt find any aluminium base material in layer stackup.

anybody help me out for this layer setings ?

Comment: As I understand you need to design as a single layer board for the copper on the top layer. There is no routing in the aluminum, its a single block. If you need two layers, you'll need to specify as described here https://www.pcbway.com/pcb_prototype/General_introduction_of_Aluminum_PCB.html